# Query in list of objects, looking for some attributes of different objects (CosmosDB SQL API)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have problems to make a query (CosmosDB SQL API), when I try to select an array of objects.
I want to know if all the arguments of my search are in different objects.

The next document should be found:

```
{
    "_id" : "97e9272d-cd7e-4a26-3245-o4e67h29beqw",
    "_type" : "Document",
    "categories" : [ 
        {
            "_name" : "PruebaCategoria", (searching by this)
            "Type" : "omega",
            "Policy number" : "1234567890",
            "date" : 1553081146391,
            "boolean" : true
        }, 
        {
            "_name" : "CategoryDemoTest",
            "Type" : "free",
            "Policy number" : "0987654321"
        }, 
        {
            "_name" : "CategoryDemoTestDates",
            "dateInitial" : 1553081146592, (and by this in range)
            "dateEnd" : 1553081146594,
            "Type" : "omega"
        }
    ],
    "partitionNumber" : 1,
    "serial" : 1
}
```

I want to replicate the next query used with mongodb API:

```
{ "categories" : { "$all" : [{ "$elemMatch" : { "dateInitial" : { "$gt" : { "$numberLong" : "1553081146591" }, "$lt" : { "$numberLong" : "1553081146593" } } } }, { "$elemMatch" : { "_name" : "PruebaCategoria" } }] } }
```

I tried the following query, but it seems that they only match if only one object has all the elements I'm looking for:

```
"SELECT VALUE c FROM c JOIN cat in c.categories WHERE cat._name=\"PruebaCategoria\" AND cat.dateInitial > 1553081146591 AND cat.dateInitial < 1553081146593"
```

Exist a method for do this type of search (with CosmosDB SQL API)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to all [Array Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-sql-query#array-functions) in cosmos db sql api, there is no such direct way to implement similar functions to `"$all"` plus `"$elemMatch"` in mongo db.

Provide [stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/stored-procedures-triggers-udfs) workaround here.

***code:***

```
function sample() {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();

    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        'SELECT * FROM c',
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            var returnArray = [];
            for(var i =0;i<feed.length;i++){
                var nameFlag = false;       
                var dateInitialFlag = false;         
                for(var j = 0;j<feed[i].categories.length;j++){              
                    if(nameFlag == false) {
                         if(feed[i].categories[j]._name == 'PruebaCategoria'){
                            nameFlag= true;
                         }
                    }
                    if(dateInitialFlag == false){
                         if(feed[i].categories[j].dateInitial <1553081146593 || feed[i].categories[j].dateInitial > 1553081146590){
                            dateInitialFlag= true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (nameFlag == true && dateInitialFlag == true) {
                        returnArray.push(feed[i]);
                        break;
                    } 
                }
            }
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody(returnArray);
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

You also could [pass arguments to SP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs#arrays-as-input-parameters-for-stored-procedures) so that you could filter the data dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for your response I tested the stored procedure with your code in database and works fine.